# How can I prevent JavaScript in an iFrame to access properties of the outer site, even if the iFrame's content comes from the same origin?

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

Basically I want to have an iFrame which always restricts it's content as if it comes from a different domain, even if the content comes from the same origin.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) or [AdSafe](http://www.adsafe.org/). They provide a wrapper for "guestcode" to prevent them from doing such things like messing with your global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide `window.parent` in the child frame/window, but not the `top` property.

BUT the `window.parent` property is STILL accessible till the end of the onload event of the child window/frame.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #wrapper {width:1000px;height:600px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        var frm = document.getElementById('childFrame');
        var win = frm.contentWindow || (frm.contentDocument && frm.contentDocument.parentWindow) || (frm.document && frm.document.parentWindow);
        if (win) win.parent = null;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <iframe id="childFrame" src="child.html" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very safe to me.  If there are *any* lingering references to the parent window anywhere in the child iframe, they'll leak out, and you'll have only the illusion of security.

Comment: There is also `top`, which, unlike `parent`, cannot be redefined.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is probably to use the HTML5 sandbox attribute on the iframe, which (by default) explicitly disables both scripting and same-origin access to the parent DOM.

Good introduction at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx

As of Dec 2012, this seems to be [supported on most current browsers](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox).