# How to avoid window reload

Tags: javascript, proxy, window.location

We are currently developing a http proxy that intercepts a url from a web and displays the content in a iframe. We are experiencing some issues with urls in JavaScript, because JavaScript urls depend on `window.location` property. Some sites modify `window.location` property and then the url redirects to the site, outside of our proxy. Is there any possibility to intercept when `window.location` changes and modify the host property pointing to our proxy url?

An example:

Our proxy url looks like this: `www.proxyweb.com?remote_web=http://www.remoteweb.com`

JavaScript code of www.remoteweb.com  excecutes `window.location.pathName="page2"`.
The result is a url like "www.proxyweb.com/page2/" 
and must be like this: "www.proxyweb.com?remote_web=www.remoteweb.com/page2". Any ideas?

Comment: i think you must check every website before adding in your system as other proxy traffic website do.. or you can moderate the website javascript code wherever you find the weindo.location for similar codes..

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this question and it's answer useful: [How can I prevent JavaScript in an iFrame to access properties of the outer site, even if the iFrame's content comes from the same origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247798/how-can-i-prevent-javascript-in-an-iframe-to-access-properties-of-the-outer-site)

More specifically, use the HTML5 Sandbox attribute, along with options to allow exceptions as I'm assuming you want the iframe to still execute JS and stuff, that should do the trick, at least for most modern browsers.

As referenced in the linked question, this page should explain more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx

Comment: sanbox attribute only prevents iframe content to modify the url in my window, but when javascript code inside iframe invokes window.location it will redirect to www.proxyweb.com/page2/ displaying NOT FOUND inside the iframe.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code / javascript of the iframed page?  If not, then I don't believe this is possible as there is really no reason you couldn't do this to "snoop" for variables from a banking website or SSO login process that uses GET variables, and this is inherently a reason why parent windows aren't allowed full access to the child's DOM.

Comment: I have access to the source code of the page in the java server webapp  (the proxy). Maybe I can generate my own javascript that replaces the javascript from server, but this is not so much generic