# Prevent access to parent from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a website, which has a few ad banners on it, and the banners. Many of these banners try to access the parent window. I need to add the website into an iFrame for preview purposes, so editors can see both the desktop and the mobile website. This works quite well, but some banners try to access the parent window, and when the parent window no longer is the main website, the content is overwritten, so the iFrame only displays the ad.

I have tried different ways to set disable access to parent window from iFrame. In HTML 5 there is an sandbox attribute for the iFrames, but I need to enable so many things, such as allow-scripts, that the banners still get access to the parent frame.

I have tried several different variants of the following code, on the page that is rendered inside the iframe:

```
// Variant 1
window._parent = window.parent;
window.parent = null;

// Variant 2
window.parent = "";

// Variant 3
window.parent = window;

// Variant 4 - from the parent document
  window.onload = function() {
    var frm = document.getElementById('childFrame');
    var win = frm.contentWindow || (frm.contentDocument && frm.contentDocument.parentWindow) || (frm.document && frm.document.parentWindow);
    if (win) win.parent = null;
  }
```

And a lot more, but you can probably see the concept, however nothing seem to work properly. Often it seems like everything goes in to a infinite loop, which makes the browser unresponsive.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247798/how-can-i-prevent-javascript-in-an-iframe-to-access-properties-of-the-outer-site

Comment: That does not solve the issue. I have tried it. The browser goes into infinite loop and freezes. Seems like that approach is similar to the above mentioned.