# Can't keep script isolated to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a script inside an iframe that looks for an element with jquery, but when it runs, it only finds an element outside the iframe - not the element that is inside the iframe.

Please help me with isolating the script to only be excecuted inside the iframe.

I have the example here: [my example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ulojA)

A picture that illustrates my example:
[image]

How I create the iframe as showned in my linked example:

```js
//Head to iframe:
var head = '<meta charset="utf-8">' +
  '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">' +
  '<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">' +
  '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"><\/script>';

//Body to iframe that contains a script that I would like only to run inside the iframe:
var body = '<code id="codeInside">code tag inside</code>' +
  '<script>var codeTag = $("code").text("TAG FOUND!!");<\/script>';

//Insert the iframe:
var iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:\'\'">').appendTo($('body'));
iframe.contents().find('head').html(head); //Append head til the iframe
iframe.contents().find('body').html(body); //Append body to the iframe
```

Comment: Post your code here, not as a link to another site.

Comment: wait, what? you using javascript to append javascript that executes javascript,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it: [a working solution](http://dojo.telerik.com/ulojA/5)

```js
//Head to iframe:
    var head = '<head><meta charset="utf-8">' +
      '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">' +
      '<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">' +
      '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"><\/script></head>';

    //Body to iframe that contains a script that I would like only to run inside the iframe:
    var body = '<body><code id="codeInside">code tag inside</code>' +
      '<script>var codeTag = $("code").text("TAG FOUND!!"); console.log("codeTag", codeTag);<\/script></body>';

    //Insert the iframe:
    var iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:\'\'">').appendTo($('body'));

    var doc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(head);
    doc.write(body);
    doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the normal way of doing it

```
var codeTag = iframe.contents().find("code").text("TAG FOUND!!"); console.log("codeTag", codeTag);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work in my case. I have to use the explained setup because i am making a dynamic way for the user to write some html and javascript and then see the result in an inserted iframe - a bit like jsfiddle.net does. So the user should be able to write normal javascript and not think about that it will be excecuted in an iframe.

Comment: this seems like a good tutorial http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: another question that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247798/how-can-i-prevent-javascript-in-an-iframe-to-access-properties-of-the-outer-site

Comment: Thanks. I have now read the link that you send and tried out some of the sugestions without luck. It takes me back to my original question - How can I get jquery to run inside the iframe. If I just can get that to wok, I can do the rest.

Comment: you may have better luck just saving and reloading the iframe

Comment: You mean saving the iframe content and refer to that in the iframe? Then I should save the content to the server. That would work and I have done that a couple a years ago, but it shouldn't be necesary to complicate the setup like that. Or are you thinking another way that I am describing?

Comment: why is it complicated, you just do a simple ajax with the content of the textarea and you build the page in your server side language, aren't you planing on saving this files that the user creates?